# Split uint16_t in bits in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

Hello I have a uint16_t number and I need to split it in 3 parts.

The first 5 bits of this number gives me the hour.

The next 6 bits of this number gives me the minutes.

The next 5 bits of this number gives me the seconds.

So I need to split it in those 3 parts to get the info I need.

any idea ?

Comment: A `uint8_t` has **8** bits, hence the name.

Comment: fixed. thanks.  Any idea to do this in C ?

Comment: Yes, I have some idea. What have you come up with so far? What are your thoughts? Hint: bitshift

Comment: Umm... bit operations, masks and some kind of built-in type for storage.

Comment: 5 bits for second? that really sound familar. Wasn't it Atari-TOS which used 2 second-steps (always wondered how they would have treaded leap-seconds)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving aside that you can't split 8 bits into 16 (I'm going to assume you actually have a uint16_t, since that makese sense here), what you want to is called a mask.  Let's say your 16 bit value is stored in variable "value"

To get the first (most significant) 5 bits, you'd use the mask 0xF800, which in binary is 1111100000000000.

You use a bitwise AND to apply this:

```
    const uint16_t MASK;
    uint16_t value = whatever_was_passed_in;
    value = value & MASK;
```

This zeros out the bits you aren't interested in.  If you want those bits shifted down to the lowest part of the variable, you can do that with a right shift:

```
    value = (value & MASK) >> 11;
```

The other chuncks are handled with the same process, but different masks and shift values.

Comment: The answer below by Andrew Henle is a better option in this case -- go with that one.  Leaving above explaination as well, since there are cases where it might make sense, but in this one use the structure option.

Comment: As long as you never try to split up the 16 bit values, then the MSB is just the MSB -- it's position never becomes an issue.  Once you try to split up values and address byte by byte, then you'd need to worry (actually, I think I assumed big endian here -- it would be a little endian system that is likely to take you by surprise).  Most likely, you'd worry about this when loading the 16 bit value initially.

Comment: It matters what the OP means by "first" and "next", but otherwise this is all endian-agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct bit_time {
   unsigned int hour:5;
   unsigned int minute:6;
   unsigned int seconds:5;
} bit_time_t;
```

[Here's a good explanation.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm)

Comment: This is a good answer (well, almost; a code dump and a link isn't really an answer but...) to some other question.

Comment: Although good for internal data structures, this is not guaranteed to work if the variable is read from a peripheral register in an MCU or a serialized datastructure like - say - an disk-directory entry (IIRC FAT had something similar for timestamps) on disc. Problem is that bitfield-structs may be allocated in a different ordering, etc. This would also prevent conversion using a union of uint16_t and bit_time_t.